# Null Layout in NetBeans-JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to add image to my login frame in Netbeans, so I try to change the layout from 'free 
Design' to 'Null Layout' (like I see in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZFgiqM0udA), and it's work.

But when I run the program the window open in the left side, and not in the regular size -
as you can see in the picture:
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the wonderful world of why you should not use `null` layouts (and why learning to code a UI with a form designer is also a bad idea).

The problem you are facing is based on the fact that Swing (and AWT) were designed to work with layout managers, this is at the core of how the framework works.

When you call `pack` on a `Window`, it asks all it's children what size they would like to be and calculates the best size for the `Window`.

In your case, because you're not using a layout manager, the window is assuming it's default side of 0x0 (plus the frame border).

To fix the issue I suggest two things.  Firstly, stop using the form designer until you understand how the UI is constructed and secondly, make use of one or more layout managers.

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

I've not had the chance to use it, but it might also be worth while to take a look at [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), it comes highly recommended by many of the users on SO

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, dont use null layout, use LayoutManagers instead, anyway, you're free, I think you're calling pack() method to the frame and you probably didnt set the aize of frame

Comment: `I think you're calling pack() method to the frame and you probably didnt set the aize of frame` - The reason for using pack() is so you don't need to set the size of the frame. The pack() method will use the preferred size of the components added to the frame to determine the frame size.

Comment: Thats what I meant, thanks for correcting me, but if he uses null lauout, dont needs to call pack(), he must do computersword to find out what will be the best size lol

Comment: ok I Set the Minimum size of the JFrame and now it work.
Thanks

Comment: @user2097810: do you see the Tick above the up-vote? It means to accept an answer, please accept my answer :(.

Comment: @user2097810, ` I Set the Minimum size of the JFrame and now it work` - that is NOT the proper solution. The proper solution is to use a layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

or you can move on and start by tamming a little the layout manager.

select your frame in the navigator and then, look for this propierties

preferredSize - The size that frame will take as their default

maximumSize   - The maximum size of the frame

minimumSize   - Minimum size of the frame

Answer (score 0):

Using Absolute Layout fixed mine! For some reason, default size 0*0 was getting executed on run ( but the frame remains in custom resolution), so changing null layout to absolute is calling the custom frame size.